# Data-binding in a NSCollectionView

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, nscollectionview, monomac

I've got a `NSCollectionView` for which I do have a `dataArray` and a `selectedIndexes` `NSIndexSet` defined in it's `File's Owner`. (Since I'm working with MonoMac on that project I've had some trouble working with a simple `NSArrayController` and so I decided to implement the source myself.) When initializing my controller I'm adding some data (`NSMutableDictionary`s) to the `dataArray`. When the application shows it's window all the data I just added is being displayed nicely.

The problem is that changes to the data source do not affect the interface in any way. Shouldn't the interface update itself automatically when I add, change or remove an item from the data source since I bound the values using it's corresponding keys?

Am I missing something? Any thoughts on that?

Thanks a lot
–f

Comment: Did you ever get this working completely?  I'm new to monomac and trying to do the same thing that you are.

Comment: me too, is there an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When binding to a to-many relationship of you data source you have to make sure that the data source is Key-Value Observing compliant for this property. It is not enough to have a public property to a mutable collection, like an `NSMutableArray`.

In the implementation of the data source, you have to use the methods from the `NSKeyValueObserving` protocol to advertise the changes you make (using `willChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:` for to-many relationships).

If performance is less important than a simple implementation you can also use an (immutable) `NSArray` for the property and always assign a new array when data changes. This way you will not get the nice animations for added or removed objects, though.

Comment: Thanks, Nikolai. That pointed me in the right direction for the Mono-related issue. The [Export] attribute seems to do the trick.